# A UIImage Gray in Swift 3 Playground URLSession Async

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Bach displays in a `.playground` file but is gray.  Toggling different `Result Display Modes` did not help.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)

var theImage = UIImageView()
let urlNew = NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg")


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlNew! as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print("thers an error in the log")
    } else {

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            theImage.image = image
        }
    }

}

task.resume()
```

What is the best way to render Bach or any `UIImageView` in a `.playground` with Swift 3.0?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's obviously downloading the proper image, it may just be a UI bug in playgrounds. You should also be able to skip the `UIImageView` and just display the `UIImage` directly.

Comment: I tried. Updating the code from `UIImageView` to `UIImage` has no effect on the gray shading.

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer just now, but I'll try to reproduce the issue later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue you're seeing, and created a playground here to illustrate: https://github.com/dtweston/Bach.playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Toggle the code below to fade the image out or display it properly
//PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let image = UIImage(named: "Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg")
```

Basically, the image appears faded while the playground is still running. Since you have `needsInfiniteExecution` set to `true`, it always appears faded.